# How do I connect to a remote printer using IPP from Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, network-printer

I am trying to connect to a remote printer
using [IPP (Internet Printing Protocol)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Printing_Protocol) from a Vista machine.
Can anyone point me to some instructions?

The owner of the Linux server it is running on has given me the URL `ipp://hostname/printers/printername`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing if you're conencting via IPP, the printer is on a [CUPS](http://www.cups.org) server

CUPS uses port 631, so you'll need to use something like http://192.168.0.1:631 for the host

Assuming you're connecting to a CUPS printer, your full URL will be in the format

http://192.168.0.1:631/printers/printer_name

substituting in the IP address of your print server and the printer name you specified in CUPS as appropriate

Comment: Did that solve the problem for you?